# Sleeping SPID with Open Transcations

Tags: sql-server, sp-whoisactive

[image: Sleeping SPID]

This is an output from `sp_whoisactive`. Should I be worried about the sleeping spids with high cpu numbers and an open transaction? The `sql_command` value is the same as `sql_text`. CPU and reads do increase over time.

I have hundreds of these at any given time...would this impact CPU?

Comment: Depends on 1) is the user a service/app account? 2) how long has it been idling? 3) is there DDL involved? 4) what are the risks of killing it? 5) are you sure there are no outer queries involved? I know that in general, a dead session with a tran count still active is a useless transaction, but a sleeping one might still have some use...maybe. Ask around

Comment: You should understand how the dm views work. Connections can have one session which in turns can have many requests. If the connection has no session which has any active requests, yet has a tran count for a long time, then I would be concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if your case is similar, but you can see similar behavior with Distribution Agent SPIDs on subscriber.

When its not applying any changes it looks something similar.

[image]

So in this case its normal behavior.

Hundreds of idle sessions, as you can imagine, would not impact CPU.  But those sessions might be waking up and doing things. The real question is where are those spids coming from? Are all of them from the same application? If so, it might be time to ask the application support guys why it has so many connections hanging around. Maybe they are not closing connections properly.